# Infinite loop when setting and using state in a `useCallback` that is being called from a `useEffect`

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I would like to fetch data when the user changes.

To do this I have a `useEffect` that triggers when the `user` changes, which calls a function to get the data.

The problem is that the `useEffect` is called too often because it has a dependency on `getData` and `getData` changes because it both uses and sets `loading`.

Are there ways around this, while still retaining `getData` as a function, as I call it elsewhere.

```
const getData = useCallback(async () => {
    if (!loading) {
      try {
        setLoading(true);

        const { error, data } = await getDataHook();
        if (error) {
         throw new Error("blah!");
        }

      } catch (error) {
        const message = getErrorMessage(error);
        setErrorMessage(message);
        setLoading(false);
      }
    }
  }, [loading]);

...

  useEffect(() => {
    const callGetData = async () => {
      await getData();
    };
    callGetData();
  }, [user, getData]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try moving `loading` from `useCallback` to `useEffect`. Something like this:

```
const getData = useCallback(async () => {
        try {
            const { error, data } = await getDataHook();
            if (error) {
             throw new Error("blah!");
            }

        } catch (error) {
            const message = getErrorMessage(error);
            setErrorMessage(message);
        }
  }, []);

...

  useEffect(() => {
    const callGetData = async () => {
      await getData();
    };
    if (!loading) {
      setLoading(true);
      callGetData();
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }, [user, getData, loading]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `loading` flag is something that the call sets, and shouldn't be effected by it, so remove it from the `useEffect()`, and `getData()` functions.

```
const getData = useCallback(async () => {
  try {
    setLoading(true);

    const { error, data } = await getDataHook();
    if (error) {
     throw new Error("blah!");
    }

  } catch (error) {
    const message = getErrorMessage(error);
    setErrorMessage(message);
  } finally {
    setLoading(false); // not related, but this would remove loading after an error as well
  }
}, []);

useEffect(() => {     
  const callGetData = async () => {
    await getData(user);
  };
  callGetData();
}, [user, getData]);
```

Comment: Had to sleep on it a bit. The `loading` flag is the cause of the problem, and it doesn't seem to have any function in the process itself. See updated answer. If this doesn't work for you, try to add more info to the question.